# Restrict the owner's ability to delete his/her own question once it reaches a certain threshold

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions

It's disconcerting to see a question that has received so much attention, often in a short time, get deleted all of a sudden.  I realize that sometimes they are deleted by mods, but I don't feel that that is the case in all such situations.  There are obviously many people that are passionate about this question, and I don't think it's right their place of discussion yanked out from under their feet without warning by the OP.  If a mod wants to delete it, that's their privilege and presumably they "know what's right" more than the OP.

I recommend removing the OP's privilege to delete his own question once it has reached enough upvotes/answers/comments.  Maybe we can create an aggregate score (answers worth 10, upvotes worth 7, comments worth 0.5) and once that is over 100 (150? 200?) the question can only be deleted by a moderator.

This should apply to all four sites.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention which question prompted this request.
[Meta is becoming a sad and depressing place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18135)

What do you think?

Comment: Bah, that question was going no where. Good riddance!

Comment: @Shog9: I just don't want it to be deleted by the user, I want it deleted by a mod and the user penalized for abuse.

Comment: This doesn't invalidate your question, but that particular post was deleted by moderators.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks, that helps a lot.  Given Ian's answer, I think my request has been satisfied.  If someone will edit the actual limit into it, I'll keep this up for dupe-prevention.

Comment: I believe that one was deleted by the mods not because it was an inappropriate question, but because it attracted a flame-war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already limits in place regarding when a question can be deleted. If any question has so much as a single answer with 2 or more up-votes, it cannot be deleted by the owner. Responses can be deleted by the owner regardless of the vote count.

The thread you're talking about was deleted by a mod, and should have been.

Comment: Are these limits listed somewhere that you can link?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specified anywhere, but I believe the limit is no answer with 2 or more up votes.

Comment: @Ian: well then I'd better delete this question before it gets another upvote!

Comment: @Rich B: there's a distinct difference between discussing waffles on Meta and discussing Meta on Meta.

Comment: Actually, testing shows this not to be true.  It appears to be dependent on how many answers are upvoted.  We we able to delete a question until an answer got two upvotes.

Comment: *Until* an answer got two up votes... Isn't that what I said? 2 or **more**?

Comment: Your comment was clear, but the answer was ambiguous.

Comment: Looking back I can see the ambiguity, thanks for the edit