# A question was deleted by the owner even though it had an upvoted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question

At the time of writing, this question:

> [Java newbie: infinite loop searching for specific text in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346657/java-newbie-infinite-loop-searching-for-specific-text-in-a-file)

has one answer with one upvote, but the owner has deleted the question.  The FAQ says "You cannot delete your own question if answers exist that have upvotes", and you can't vote on an answer to a deleted question.

Bug?  Timing window?  Pixies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to be coy about exactly what is required here (the exact number of answers and votes required to prevent owner deletion), to prevent gaming.

But the rules are enforced.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  (But how can you game the system by deleting your own questions?  What am I missing?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the FAQ is wrong.

Here, upvote me and then try to delete the question. (If you can delete it, just undelete it afterward and let us know.)

Comment: Good idea, but no joy: "Sorry, this question cannot be deleted: too many existing answers, or upvoted/accepted answers."

Comment: Interesting. The example you give is just one answer with just one upvote. Maybe it needs two? Or maybe I have no idea.

Comment: Or maybe it is a race condition after all. We'll have to see what Geoff Atwould says.

Answer (score 1):

The user deleted the question because s/he solved the problem. Voted to undelete. Just need two more folks with the undelete powers to help me out with that one...

Can a mod send the SO OP a quick note explaining how we don't delete questions that get answered?

Comment: Willy the Blizzard beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

This came up yesterday, and was addressed here: 
[Restrict the owner’s ability to delete his/her own question once it reaches a certain threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18276/restrict-the-owners-ability-to-delete-his-her-own-question-once-it-reaches-a-cer)

Comment: That question still lacks an authoritative answer as to what the rules are - until we have that, either the FAQ is wrong or there's a bug.